# OpenCV copy irregular contour region to another image after contour rotation

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am working with an image with distorted/rotated texts. I need to rotate these text blobs back to the horizontal level (0 degrees) before I can run OCR on them. I managed to fix the rotation issue but now I need to find a way to copy the contents of the original contour to the rotated matrix.

Here are a few things I've done to extract and fix the rotation issue:

1. Find contour
2. Heavy dilation and remove non-text lines
3. Find the contour angle and do angle correction in the polar space.

I have tried using affine transformation to rotate the rectangle text blobs but it ended up cropping out some of the texts because some of the text blobs are irregular. [Result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS47l.jpg)

Blue dots in the contours are centroids, the numbers are contour angles. How can I copy the content of unrotated contour, rotate them and copy to a new image?
[image]

**Code**

```
def getContourCenter(contour):
    M = cv2.moments(contour)
    if M["m00"] != 0:
        cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
        cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
    else:
        return 0, 0
    return int(cx), int(cy)

def rotateContour(contour, center: tuple, angle: float):

    def cart2pol(x, y):
        theta = np.arctan2(y, x)
        rho = np.hypot(x, y)
        return theta, rho

    def pol2cart(theta, rho):
        x = rho * np.cos(theta)
        y = rho * np.sin(theta)
        return x, y

    # Translating the contour by subtracting the center with all the points
    norm = contour - [center[0], center[1]]

    # Convert the points to polar co-ordinates, add the rotation, and convert it back to Cartesian co-ordinates.
    coordinates = norm[:, 0, :]
    xs, ys = coordinates[:, 0], coordinates[:, 1]
    thetas, rhos = cart2pol(xs, ys)

    thetas = np.rad2deg(thetas)
    thetas = (thetas + angle) % 360
    thetas = np.deg2rad(thetas)

    # Convert the new polar coordinates to cartesian co-ordinates
    xs, ys = pol2cart(thetas, rhos)
    norm[:, 0, 0] = xs
    norm[:, 0, 1] = ys

    rotated = norm + [center[0], center[1]]
    rotated = rotated.astype(np.int32)

    return rotated


def straightenText(image, vis):

    # create a new mat
    mask = 0*np.ones([image.shape[0], image.shape[1], 3], dtype=np.uint8)

    # invert pixel index arrangement and dilate aggressively
    dilate = cv2.dilate(~image, ImageUtils.box(33, 1))

    # find contours
    _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    for contour in contours:
        [x, y, w, h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        if w > h:

            # find contour angle and centers
            (x, y), (w, h), angle = cv2.minAreaRect(contour)
            cx, cy = getContourCenter(contour)

            # fix angle returned
            if w < h:
                angle = 90 + angle

            # fix contour angle
            rotatedContour = rotateContour(contour, (cx, cy), 0-angle)

            cv2.drawContours(vis, contour, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.drawContours(mask, rotatedContour, -1, (255, 0, 0), 2)
            cv2.circle(vis, (cx, cy), 2, (0, 0, 255), 2, 8) # centroid
            cv2.putText(vis, str(round(angle, 2)), (cx, cy), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (255,0,0), 2)
```

Comment: Why are you doing 0*np.ones()? You can just use np.zeros().

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, which is the simplest way I can think to do it in Python/OpenCV, though may not be optimal in speed.

- Create a white empty image for the desired output. (So we have black text on white background in case you need to do OCR)
- Get the rotated bounding rectangle of your contour in your input.
- Get the normal bounding rectangle of your contour in the output.
- Get the 4 bounding box corners for each.
- Compute an affine transform matrix between the two sets of 4 corner
  points.
- Warp the (whole) input image to the same size (non-optimal).
- Use the output bounding box dimensions and upper left corner with
  numpy slicing to transfer the region in the warped image to the same
  region in the white output image.
- Repeat for each text contour using the resulting image in place of
  the original white image as the new destintination image.

So here is a simulation to show you how.

Source Text Image:

[image]

Source Text Image with Red Rotated Rectangle:

[image]

Desired Bounding Rectangle in White Destination Image:

[image]

Text Transferred To White Image into Desired Rectangle Region:

[image]

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read source text image.
src = cv2.imread('text_on_white.png')
hs, ws, cs = src.shape

# Read same text image with red rotated bounding box drawn.
src2 = cv2.imread('text2_on_white.png')

# Read white image showing desired output bounding box.
src2 = cv2.imread('text2_on_white.png')

# create white destination image
dst = np.full((hs,ws,cs), (255,255,255), dtype=np.uint8)

# define coordinates of bounding box in src
src_pts = np.float32([[51,123], [298,102], [300,135], [54,157]])

# size and placement of text in dst is (i.e. bounding box):
xd = 50
yd = 200
wd = 249
hd = 123
dst_pts = np.float32([[50,200], [298,200], [298,234], [50,234]])

# get rigid affine transform (no skew)
# use estimateRigidTransform rather than getAffineTransform so can use all 4 points
matrix = cv2.estimateRigidTransform(src_pts, dst_pts, 0)

# warp the source image
src_warped = cv2.warpAffine(src, matrix, (ws,hs), cv2.INTER_AREA, borderValue=(255,255,255))

# do numpy slicing on warped source and place in white destination
dst[yd:yd+hd, xd:xd+wd] = src_warped[yd:yd+hd, xd:xd+wd]

# show results
cv2.imshow('SRC', src)
cv2.imshow('SRC2', src2)
cv2.imshow('SRC_WARPED', src_warped)
cv2.imshow('DST', dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save results
cv2.imwrite('text_on_white_transferred.png', dst)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I have tried with this approach but I need to avoid using a rectangle as my source bounding box because when my image is tilted too much, defining a rectangle will crop in/out some neighbor texts. See [this image](https://imgur.com/a/xmHI7Mg). Green borders are the exact text area I want to rotate, red border areas are the rectangle from the contour.

Comment: That will not happen if you use a rotated rectangle and use the bounding box vertices as in my code. See rotated rectangle using cv2.minAreaRect() at https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

Comment: I am aware of this. I'm thinking to try to do this in individual pixel level

Answer (score 0):

To extract ONLY the content of a single contour, and not its larger bounding box, you can create a mask by drawing a filled contour and then applying that to the original image. In your case you would need something like this:

```
# prepare the target image
resX,resY = image.shape[1],image.shape[0]
target = np.zeros((resY, resX , 3), dtype=np.uint8)  
target.fill(255)  # make it entirely white

# find the contours
allContours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# then perform rotation, etc, per contour
for contour in allContours:
  # create empty mask
  mask = np.zeros((resY, resX , 1), dtype=np.uint8)  

  # draw the contour filled into the mask
  cv2.drawContours(mask, [contour], -1, (255),  thickness=cv2.FILLED) 
  
  # copy the relevant part into a new image 
  # (you might want to use bounding box here for more efficiency)
  single = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)   

  # then apply your rotation operations both on the mask and the result
  single = doContourSpecificOperation(single)
  mask = doContourSpecificOperation(mask)

  # then, put the result into your target image (which was originally white)
  target = cv2.bitwise_and(target, single, mask=mask)
```